# How do I Return an Invoice in Dyamics GP through eConnect or Web Services?

Tags: dynamics-gp, econnect

We have invoice documents in GP 10.0.  Recently, the accounting department has decided that when the incorrect client has been billed, we will return the invoice and create a new one.  (Previously, we would issue a credit memo to the wrong client and a debit memo to the new client).

I have been pointed at taSopHdrIvcInsert, but I'm not sure what to do with it or how to save it back.  Because I'm never 100% sure what fields GP really needs, I was hoping I could use eConnect or web services to get the document by number, change the SOPTYPE to 4-Return and save it back since it appears everything else should be the same.

I can then invoice the new client and save that into GP using existing processes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer over on the Dynamics GP Forums.  The Web Service did have a method for me to use that was called CreateSalesReturn.  I used the Web Service to pull back the invoice, and then I populated a SalesReturn object from the invoice's data and used CreateSalesReturn to get it into GP.

Comment: Can you include the solution you received from the Dynamics GP Forums?

Comment: That was the solution I received.  I populated a SalesReturn object with the invoice data, and called CreateSalesReturn() on Dynamics GP Web Services.  That solved the problem.  Previously, I had been trying to modify and save back a SalesDocument of type invoice as type return.  That was incorrect, I needed to call CreateSalesReturn()